# Image move on touch event

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event

I have two images placed one on top of another and a button with arrow marks.  When the user touches the arrow and moves toward left, the right-side image should become visible, when the user touches the arrow and moves toward right, the left-side side image should become fully visible. What would be the best way to implement this?

[image]
the below is the image

Answer (score 0):

try http://negativeprobability.blogspot.in/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html to achive this